# How does the last integer promotion rule ever get applied in C?

Tags: c, integer, standards

> 6.3.1.8p1: Otherwise, the integer promotions are
>   performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands: If both operands have the same
>   type, then no further conversion is needed. Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer
>   types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>   then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type. Otherwise,
>   if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>   **Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type.**

For the bolded rule to be applied it would seem to imply you need to have have an unsigned integer type who's rank is less than the signed integer type ***and*** the signed integer type cannot hold all the values of the unsigned integer type.

Is there a real world example of such a case or is this statement serving as a catch-all to cover all possible permutations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had a platform where `sizeof(long int)==sizeof(int)`, then `signed long int` and `unsigned int` would fall into this rule. In any case, the standard does not dictate that conversion rank is equivalent to size, only that conversion rank provides an ordering that is a valid ordering on size (6.3.1.1.p1.1 (sp?)):

> No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same
>   representation.

Comment: In this case, `long` has greater rank than `unsigned int`, but can't represent all its values, so both operands are converted to `unsigned long`.  Which means that, for example, `-1L * 1U` will be a large positive number.